# Dynamic programming state calculations

Tags: c++, dynamic, state

Question:

```
Fox Ciel is writing an AI for the game Starcraft and she needs your help. 



In Starcraft, one of the available units is a mutalisk. Mutalisks are very useful for harassing Terran bases. Fox Ciel has one mutalisk. The enemy base contains one or more Space Construction Vehicles (SCVs). Each SCV has some amount of hit points. 



When the mutalisk attacks, it can target up to three different SCVs.
The first targeted SCV will lose 9 hit points.
The second targeted SCV (if any) will lose 3 hit points.
The third targeted SCV (if any) will lose 1 hit point.
If the hit points of a SCV drop to 0 or lower, the SCV is destroyed. Note that you may not target the same SCV twice in the same attack. 



You are given a int[] HP containing the current hit points of your enemy's SCVs. Return the smallest number of attacks in which you can destroy all these SCVs.

Constraints-
-   x will contain between 1 and 3 elements, inclusive.
-   Each element in x will be between 1 and 60, inclusive.
```

And the solution is:

```
int minimalAttacks(vector<int> x)
{
    int dist[61][61][61];
    memset(dist, -1, sizeof(dist));
    dist[0][0][0] = 0;
    for (int total = 1; total <= 180; total++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 60 && i <= total; i++) {
            for (int j = max(0, total - i - 60); j <= 60 && i + j <= total; j++) {
                // j >= max(0, total - i - 60) ensures that k <= 60
                int k = total - (i + j);
                int & res = dist[i][j][k];

                res = 1000000;
                // one way to avoid doing repetitive work in enumerating
                // all options is to use c++'s next_permutation,
                // we first createa vector:
                vector<int> curr = {i,j,k};
                sort(curr.begin(), curr.end()); //needs to be sorted
                // which will be permuted 
                do {
                    int ni = max(0, curr[0] - 9);
                    int nj = max(0, curr[1] - 3);
                    int nk = max(0, curr[2] - 1);
                    res = std::min(res, 1 + dist[ni][nj][nk] );

                } while (next_permutation(curr.begin(), curr.end()) );
            }
        }
    }
    // get the case's respective hitpoints:
    while (x.size() < 3) {
        x.push_back(0); // add zeros for missing SCVs
    }
    int a = x[0], b = x[1], c = x[2];        
    return dist[a][b][c];
}
```

As far as i understand, this solution calculates all possible state's best outcome first then simply match the queried position and displays the result.  But I dont understand the way this code is written. I can see that nowhere dist[i][j][k] value is edited. By default its -1. So how come when i query any dist[i][j][k] I get a different value?. 
Can someone explain me the code please?

Thank you!

Comment: `int & res = dist[i][j][k];` captures a reference (`res`) to a value in the `dist` array, so any modifications to `res` later actually modify the value in the array.